# Is it possible to disable the two-finger-double-tap for visual accessibility?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

Windows Phone 8 has a native, two-finger-double-tap gesture that is active in the operating system, native applications, and in custom applications. The two-finger-double-tap basically zooms the screen so that anyone with visual impairment can access the content more easily.

I have discovered that the two-finger-double-tap interferes with two simultaneous one-finger-double-taps collected by the FrameReported event. As a result, in some app scenarios, it might be necessary to disable the native two-finger-double-tap for visual accessibility.

**Is it possible to programatically disable the visual accessibility tap?**

Answer (score 0):

Just set `UseOptimizedManipulationRouting` property of your control to false.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can find information about this property.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Do you write in your (for example) ManipulationStartedEvent: `e.Handled = true`?